Finding out the correct Rds(on) value for design of the overcurrent circuit
We are designing a DSAT/OC circuit for our chosen SiC module(MSCSM120HM16CTBL3NG) ,
The Overcurrent circuit is shown below:

To decide the proper resistor divider values , we need to know the correct Rds(on) value so that we can calculate the drop across the SiC mosfet(Vds), (which will be needed to calculate the thresholds for the voltage divider).
Looking at the datasheet of this SIC module, I see a range of Rds(on) values.
In the absolute value section, RDs(on) is mentioned as 16 mOhms

In the electrical characteristic's , Rds(on) ranges from 12.5 to 16 mOhm at Tj of 25 deg C

And finally in the Rds(on) vs Junction temperature , they mention a range of values, Here the Rds(on) is normalized, so 1.0 corresponds to what ? (12.5mOhm or 16 mOhm or some other..)

Assuming operation within temperature range (25 to 100 degrees), I am confused what is the Rds(on) we need to consider? Please Help

Don't worry about Rds(on):

To measure this precisely, and still operate within a cycle, the bandwidth has to be quite high, in particular the settling time.  This is at odds with the large-value resistors and diode, for example.
Desat protection is about fault protection.  Something's already gone bad and you don't too much care about how much it's gone bad by.  It's very all-or-nothing so you don't need a precise threshold to discriminate the fault condition.  More important is masking the turn-on transient properly (particularly in hard switching), and avoiding interference due to opposing side hard turn-on.

Setting a fairly gross, but safe (for normal operation) threshold, like 5 or 10V, is good enough.
Compare to nominal worst-case drop of, say, 16mΩ * 1.6 temp multiplier * 100A = 2.56V.
If you need peak current control or limiting, do peak current control!  This is an excellent control method for most switching applications, and is a front-line defense against overcurrent into the normal load path.  Then you have desat protection for fast reaction (in case the control loop isn't faster), and for exceptional load paths -- like a shorted opposing transistor/diode, debris/arcing on the connections, etc.

Power FET RDSON will always span a range. This comes from manufacturing variations, and temperature variations.
As you show, the value at 25 C is typically 12.5 and could be 16 mΩ. Note the minimum value is not specified. While it could (theoretically) be 1 mΩ, it is unlikely to be less than 8 mΩ.
The temperature curve shows the fractional variation from the room temperature value (that's what "normalized" means). You can see that at +175 C, the value is about 1.55 times the room temperature value. This agrees with the data sheet of 12.5 mΩ rising to 20 mΩ. Note a 16 mΩ device at room temperature could be 16*1.55 = 25 mΩ. Be aware that at temperatures cooler than 25 C, RDSON could be even lower than 8 mΩ.
RDSON will also be affected by the gate voltage slightly (say 10 %), and your circuit will certainly be affected by how you apply Kelvin connections to the device.
So, you can expect (over temperature and manufacturing variations), RDSON from (say) 8 mΩ to 25 mΩ. This span is not unusual.
If you need accurate sensing, you will a) need to 'calibrate' for the individual device, and b) need to compensate for temperature variations.
The simple circuit you show is not safe. If the diode fails, the (1.2 kV) HV will pass into the low V IC, cause it to fail and also will become a safety hazard. In addition, capacitive coupling across the diode will bring dangerous voltages to the top of R2, and also possibly into the IC.
If you are not familiar with the concepts above, I suggest you do NOT experiment with 1.2 kV, 100+ A systems.
